# Strapi routes return 404 Not found

Tags: docker, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I have a problem where all routes in my API return `404 Not found`. I followed the **Pull from Docker Hub** section at [strapi/strapi-docker](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker#pull-from-docker-hub).

What I did, apart from running the images, was creating a new Content type called `post` containing three fields. If I try `GET /post` (to get all posts added) I get unauthorized response error. This is expected at this stage. After I check Roles & Permissions to allow the Public role to use the find and findOne routes I instead get a 404 Not found response error even though data has been added.

The dev server does not use any prefix.

`post` routes for find and findOne looks as the following:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/post",
    "handler": "Post.find",
    "config": {
      "policies": []
    }
  },
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/post/:_id",
    "handler": "Post.findOne",
    "config": {
      "policies": []
    }
  }
}
```

There are not many options in the strapi interface to fiddle with so I'm not sure what else to try. I have tried a couple of other installations of strapi. Not sure if that could have messed it up but I vaguely remember trying out strapi/strapi-docker before and getting it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have stumbled upon this issue many times, and the easiest answer usually is:

Have you published any of your posts?

Strapi has a publishing subsystem which is usually turned on upon the creation of any collection, single type or component.
[image]

So when you create any content of any created type, the data is saved as draft and is not publicly available.

Here is my link collection type. It is saved, but not published.

[image]

So if you are trying to test an endpoint, but you only have one single data entry and it is set to draft, no data will show up.

[image]

No data!

[image]

In case of a single type that is not published

[image]

This will return a 404!

[image]

Publish and, voila ...

[image]

This could be one reason why strapi is sending you a 404 or only an empty array!

Comment: It's years later but your answer helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've had this issue many times as well, even with published content.

Two additional causes could be:

1. if your content type is posts try /posts as well as /api/posts (the 2nd usually works for me
2. Under Settings > Roles (the one under USERS & PERMISSIONS plugins) make sure both **Authenticated** and **Public** user roles have **find** and **findOne** access to the content type.

One time I was getting the 404 even though I did this for **Public**...but because I was in the same browser as my logged in admin and needed to update it for **Authenticated** as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this is publish button, and sometimes it doesn't work if you have a convoluted component where one section errors but the screen does not scroll to it, therefore publish button seems to do nothing, logs show only a get request and you start pulling your hair...

Well don't, always check the page when publishing for any errors ie missing required field etc so that publish button works.