# Strapi API Rest V 3.6.8 how to search posts by title?

Tags: rest, search, filtering, strapi

I have installed version 3.6.8 of Strapi

In the docs for v3.x
https://strapi.gitee.io/documentation/v3.x/content-api/parameters.html#filter

Filters are used as a suffix of a field name:

- No suffix or eq: Equals
- `ne`: Not equals
- `lt`: Less than
- `gt`: Greater than
- `lte`: Less than or equal to
- `gte`: Greater than or equal to
- `in`: Included in an array of values
- `nin`: Isn't included in an array of values
- `contains`: Contains
- `ncontains`: Doesn't contain
- `containss`: Contains case sensitive
- `ncontainss`: Doesn't contain case sensitive
- `null`: Is null/Is not null

And I can see those examples

> GET /restaurants?_where[price_gte]=3

> GET /restaurants?id_in=3&id_in=6&id_in=8

etc..

So I tried

```
/posts?_where[title_contains]=foo
/posts?title_contains=foo
```

And I also tried the "new way" in V4

```
/posts?filters[title][contains]=foo
```

But all of this attempts return all the post, exactly the same than just doing

```
/posts?
```

Any idea how to filter by post title and/or post body?

Answer (score 0):

Almost there my friend! The issue you are facing called [deep filtering](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/filtering-locale-publication.html#deep-filtering) (please follow the link for documentation).

**In Short:** the `title` field is located inside the `attributes` object for each item

Your items may look something similar to this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Restaurant A",
        "description": "Restaurant A's description"
      },
      "meta": {
        "availableLocales": []
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Restaurant B",
        "description": "Restaurant B's description"
      },
      "meta": {
        "availableLocales": []
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

And therefor the filter should be

```
/api/posts?filters[attributes][title][$contains]=Restaurant
```

Also note:

- the `$` sign that should be included for your operator (in our case `contains`)
- the `api` prefix you should use before the `plural api id` (e.g. `posts`, `users`, etc.)
- you may prefer using `$containsi` operator in order to ignore upper and lower case letters (better for searching operations)

Let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: thank you very much but no.. it's also returning all the posts..

Comment: any chance to attach some items? to better clarify the structure of the data set you are trying to query

Comment: i'm not sure what do you need, could you clarify? and also note that (i'm not sure the reason) the /api/ endpoint returns 404, i'm tring https://example.com/posts?filters[attributes][title][$contains]=xxxx

Comment: can you add to your question some `posts` items? it's hard to understand what is not working using only the query with no data.. also - please verify you used the `/api` prefix to your calls

Comment: about getting 404 when using `/api` prefix - please follow this question to resolve this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042524/strapi-routes-return-404-not-found

Comment: Due privacy I can't share the posts that are returned, but with the url I provided (and is the same that you answered without the /api/ ALL the post are returned, so the filter is ignored ), I'll will look on the last resource you sent and see if the missing /api/ is the reason

Comment: sorry the late response is that we don't have /api/ on the "Bound route to post.find" field.. but i noticed that this link you provided https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/filtering-locale-publication.html#deep-filtering is for the latest Strapi (v4) and we still using 3.6.8

Comment: I have not seen using `attributes` mentioned in any of their documentation while if I use it, I get an `Invalid parameter attributes` error.